# How are ERC20 EOS tokens converted to main net tokens?

Tags: tokens, voting, token-registration

So the ERC20 tokens have been registered and locked. Now they need to be represented on main net. How is this achieved?

What does the cross chain swap look like? How do I prove to EOS main net that I am the owner of the registered ERC20 tokens ?

Does keosd interact with ethereum ?

I don't want to use some random portal. Ideally, I would like to handle it myself on the CLI.

I would also like to be able to try it with a small part of the token stake in case I make a mistake. In hindsight it would have been prudent to keep them in multiple ethereum wallets with some low values to test the process first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EOS.IO token are not refering to ethereum or erc20 tokens anymore.

Blockproducers took a snapshot of the erc20 token by the transactions on ethereum. This is now the initial distribution/balance of EOS token. If you have registered your ethereum adress the account name is holding the tokens on EOS now. A snapshot file of one blockproducer can be fund [here](https://github.com/eoscafe/eos-snapshot-validation/blob/master/eosdac/snapshot.csv). After validation and consensus between the blockproducer this is your balance.

You can verify your ownership of your account by using the (EOS) public/private key pair you have created while registering your erc20 tokens.

Now there is no communication to ethereum anymore. So any voting tool or cli for EOS is communicating with the EOS mainnet.

In addition for the voting process there are some tokens staked already. Afterwards you can use your token as you wish.

For testing you can use a testnet or local hosted EOS blockchain.

---

**Edit**

You can easily check your EOS account name and balance by inserting a **public key or ethereum address** at the [EOSAuthority hompage](https://eosauthority.com/). Please **never insert your private key** into some tool you don't know or trust.

Comment: thank you, that explains what I missed. I used Exodus wallet because I was lazy and it solved the registration very easily. It didn't explain the details though that the private key that can be exported later was a future main net EOS key