# How to trade EOS mainnet token after Launch Day?

Tags: tokens

As ERC20 token is frozen and mapped to "mainnet token". So for now, is there a way to trade mainnet token using USD or BTC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are ERC20 EOS tokens converted to main net tokens?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/855/how-are-erc20-eos-tokens-converted-to-main-net-tokens)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about exchanges, they have not yet been ready for user to deposit their EOS. Now ERC20 token is frozen and illegible to trade what people are trading now is the representative of their holding of EOS on exchanges.

Besides, similar to any user, exchanges have to create account name to be able for user to deposit their EOS. I guess it's quite different from other cryptocurrencies so it would take more time for them than usual for security reason.

Now mainnet is online and what people are waiting for are exchanges not EOS community neither Block.one

Answer (score 0):

No. I am assuming you have a EOS wallet with your EOS tokens in it and wanting to trade it with others for BTC or USD.  Not possible without doing some over the counter (OTC) transactions in a peer to peer manner.