# Migrate ERC20 token from Ethereum blockchain to EOS blockchain

Tags: smart-contract, tokens

How do migrate ERC20 token from the Ethereum blockchain to the EOS blockchain?

Or how can I operate (transfer) ERC20 tokens from smart-contract in Ethereum network when using EOS smart-contracts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are ERC20 EOS tokens converted to main net tokens?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/855/how-are-erc20-eos-tokens-converted-to-main-net-tokens)

Comment: Are you asking about the EOS initial token sale, or other ERC20 tokens?

Comment: No, I'm asking about the ERC20 standard already released token, not about the EOS token

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to migrate ERC20 tokens from Etherum blockchain to EOS blockchain. If I understand this question correctly, you need a interchain blockchain like Wanchain to programmatically move tokens (or perhaps their equivalent value) between chains. Sorry, if this is not the answer you are looking for.