# How is the the crash of a BP handled?

Tags: block-producer, blocks, blockchains

I am wondering if a BP crashes, how do the remaining 20 BPs know this?

If they do not know, all block not irreversible so we can be hack?
Please give me some details for this. Thanks!

Comment: Based on [this discussion](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/q/3438/15).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there aren't any alert mechanisms that notify the BPs.

In terms of block production, they skip the BP that crashed(with a moderate time delay).

Given that there are more than 1/3 BPs crashed and were not confirming blocks, they are not included in the LIB. When the BPs return, they confirm the blocks and add to LIB.

In terms of hacking(or modifying blocks I persume), I'm not sure whats the risk, but my guess is if they are able to create a falsified block that is not detected by the EOS software.. maybe?

Comment: Thank you, I do not think so, I think EOS will use system contract to detect this

Comment: I am not aware of any system contract code that detects crashed block producers.

Comment: Hi, It is  maybe very not clearly. So if some BPs down, currently we do not have a way to detect it. But in bnet_plugin I saw a ping/ping message, but I still read more. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: Bnet_plugins are for synchronization as far as i know. Could you share the source where you read bnet_plugin's ping message ?
And yes, I don't think there's a systematic way to detect and to alert if the BP has crashed. Unless you add a 3rd party checker (which is pretty simple to do in my opinion)

Comment: You can see it by https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/plugins/bnet_plugin/bnet_plugin.cpp#L716

Comment: You can probably tell that the code only checks whether the BP is up and running. It doesn't quite have any other affect in terms of alerting. I'm sure you can modify the code to print out some kind of message if need be, but as far as I know. This feature is not available at the moment

Comment: Yep, it is not available now. And I see function deactivate() in eosio.system.hpp but it is not available at the moment. By that way, I think we can use ping/pong message and this deactivate()  to update producer table. Do you think so?